# Obtener un valor concreto de un dataframe a partir de un condicional - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe que viene del archivo wod.csv, una de sus columnas es `codigo` y a partir de ella quiero obtener los diferentes valores de las otras columnas.

Por ahora consigo filtrar por códigos de la siguiente manera,

```
print(wod[wod['codigo'] == codigo])
```

Y obtengo lo siguiente:

```
   codigo  vueltas  porcentaje  cap grupo muscular  material
1  w0002        2        0.75   30      full body      True
```

La cosa es que yo querría por ejemplo obtener el número de vueltas, no toda la fila entera, para ello pienso que debo emplear `loc` pero no sé donde colocarlo cuando se emplean condicionales.

```
print(wod.loc[1]['vueltas']) #sin condicional, sabiendo la fila
```

Comment: ¿No sería `print(wod[wod['codigo'] == codigo].vueltas)` lo que buscas?

Comment: Entonces `wod[wod['codigo']==codigo]['grupo muscular']`. En definitiva, tu expresión condicional te devuelve otro dataframe que sólo tiene las filas que te interesan, y en ese dataframe accedes a las columnas de la forma habitual, ya sea con su nombre entre corchetes, o si el nombre no tiene espacios con el atajo del punto.

Answer (score 1):

```
# filtrar dataframe
dataframe_filtrado = wod[wod['codigo'] == codigo]
# seleccionar columna 'vueltas'
vueltas = dataframe_filtrado['vueltas']
# vueltas es un objeto tipo Series que contiene los valores de la columna filtrada
print(vueltas)
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar loc de esta forma:

```
wod.loc[wod['codigo'] == codigo,'vueltas']
```

Fijate que estas seleccionando las filas mediante indexación booleana y despues eliges la columna.

Si quisieras obtener tambien la columna porcentaje necesitas poner las etiquetas de laa colummas en una lista:

```
wod.loc[wod['codigo'] == codigo,['vueltas','porcentaje']]
```

Si conoces el valor de la fila deberías usar iloc:

```
wod.iloc[1]['codigo']
```